# Problem with first sync in revived Ropsten Ethereum

Tags: synchronization, ropsten, ethereumjs, linux

Hello everyone i would like to sync to Ropsten test network for the first time.I use linux mint.First i followed the instruction [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu) and execute the commands

- sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
- sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
- sudo apt-get update

I need to use geth1.5.9 that allows the command web3.eth.complile.solidity so i thought i should not execute the command "sudo apt-get install ethereum" and instead i downloaded geth 1.5.9 version from [here](https://ethereum.github.io/go-ethereum/downloads/). Then i extracted the .tar.gz in Downloads folder. After that i opened a new terminal and went to Downloads and in the folder i had extracted.Then i run the command

```
./geth --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --rpcaddr="localhost"
--rpcport="8545" --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:3000" --testnet --bootnodes
"enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1
510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:303
03,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9
216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30
303"
```

In order to sync in the revived Ropsten. I left it running and after 8hours in some blocks(number 589K) it wrote synchronization failed: state data download canceled..i left it running and it seemed to keep downloading blocks(but the block number was smaller 585K before the error was 589K) but with much slower pace. I left it running for another 8hours until i saw it downloaded every block very slowly(imported 1 block) and the number of the block was 588K very close to the number i left it 8hours ago(585K). I read in some forum that that means the sync failed.So:

1. are my steps for installation of ethereum and geth right? Because instead of the command "sudo apt-get install ethereum" i thought it would be the same to go to the folder containing geth 1.5.9 and execute the commands there with ./geth (command)
2. When i executed the command ./geth --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --rpcaddr="localhost"...(as described above) i got a message: no etherbase set and no accounts found. How can i create an account in ropsten ethereum test network? Could that be the cause that sync failed?

I am sorry for the long post, i am trying to be as clear as i can.Also i am new to the forum so i am sorry if i accidentally violated any rules of the forum.

Comment: I'd suggest to use the more recent version, the new version have security fixes and improvements for denial of service attacks. If you want to compile from javascript you can use `https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js`.

Comment: I want to use web3.eth.compile.solidity in a dapp that uses meteor so from what i read solcjs is not what i need(i am not pretty sure though as i am still learning about dapps)..but thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I experience problems on the ropsten network as well. transactions that were put in are now unable to locate or have extreme long latency. Will probably have to do with the upcoming hardfork planned on block 1.7M. Most of the time, time will heal this all, but can be very frustrating if it happens while you need the network.